# How to add routes by symfony matching HTTP methods?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I would like to use the methods option to restrict the route it should respond to (GET, POST, PUT, etc.).

Based on the code below, how to access the `return function` so that `$app` will contain the added `routes`?

```
// config/routes.php
$app = new App\Config\Core();

use App\Controller\BlogApiController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
    $routes->add('api_post_show', '/api/posts/{id}')
        ->controller([BlogApiController::class, 'show'])
        ->methods(['GET', 'HEAD'])
    ;
    $routes->add('api_post_edit', '/api/posts/{id}')
        ->controller([BlogApiController::class, 'edit'])
        ->methods(['PUT'])
    ;
};

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $app->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are trying to accomplish.  The RoutingConfigurator is typically used from inside of the Symfony framework to configure routes yet you seem to be developing some sort of standalone application?  Are you perhaps asking how to use the Router component standalone?

Comment: @Cerad, Yes, I'm using Router component as standalone

Comment: The component documentation is a bit sparse to say the least though there is a [getting started example](https://github.com/symfony/routing#readme).  But besides the router you also seem to want to use the HTTP Kernel class for the Request/Response processing.  By the time you get all that configured you may as well just use the Symfony skeleton framework.

Comment: @Cerad, I use the 'handle' function in the HTTP Kernel class, I just cannot figured out how to use the 'return function' as standalone solution

Comment: The fact that your are using one file in your question is confusing.  The config/routes.php file returns an actual function.  Your application file should include the routes.php file and then call the function with a properly configured routing configurator.  And then ultimately you would pull the routing collection from the configurator to build a router.  But that all seems overkill for a standalone application.  Do you have a github repo link you could post showing all the files involved?

Comment: [This is a repo](https://github.com/cerad/routing) that shows how to use annotated routes in a standalone application.  Perhaps it might help.

Comment: @Cerad, Thank you for your explanation and for the example that you sent.